# forward POST x-www-form-urlencoded to another POST arrives with empty req.body

Tags: node.js, express, post, x-www-form-urlencoded

A 3rd party API uses a local bash agent to send data from local machine to itself (here is a simplified version):
`wget -q -T 25 --post-data "aa=bb&cc=dd" --no-check-certificate "$url"`

The machine in question uses an internet from an ISP that blocks the 3rd party address, so I tried to create a proxy server that will receive the data from the agent and forward it to the 3rd party server. **The problem is that the forwarded req.body arrives as an empty object and I don't understand why.**
Here is a simplified node.js code that fails of the proxy API and a simulated API for the 3rd party:

```
const http = require('http')
const compression = require('compression')
const express = require('express')

const httpServerPort = process.env.SERVER_PORT   /// SET YOUR PORT

const app = express()
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: '50mb' }))
app.use(compression())

const httpServer = http.createServer(app)

httpServer.listen(httpServerPort, () => {
    console.log(`HTTP server started on port ${httpServerPort}`)
})

app.post('/api/v1/agent_proxy', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const postData = querystring.stringify(req.body)
//        console.log(postData)
        const options = {
            hostname: 'localhost',
            port: httpServerPort,
            path: '/api/v1/simu_api',
            method: 'POST',
            Headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "Content-Length": Buffer.byteLength(postData)
            }
        }

        const innerReq = http.request(options, (innerRes) => {
            innerRes.on('data', (d) => {
                console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`) 
                res.sendStatus(200)
            });
        });

        innerReq.on('error', (error) => {
            console.error(error)
            res.sendStatus(500)
        });

        innerReq.write(postData)
        innerReq.end()

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
        res.sendStatus(501)
    }
})

app.post('/api/v1/simu_api', async (req, res) => {
    try {
////////// HERE I CAN SEE THE PROBLEM OF req.body == {} WHILE IT SHOULD BE EQUAL TO {aa: 'bb', cc: 'dd'} /////////
        console.log(req.body) 
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
        res.sendStatus(501)
    }
    res.sendStatus(200)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the options object, I wrote "Headers" instead of "headers". That's it.